# always-on VPN connection that doesn't leak?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, vpn

I'm using Fedora 25. Trying to make it so the PC can only connect to the internet through a VPN tunnel.

This means:

- when the VPN connection drops or hasn't yet been established, it must be unable to connect to the internet outside of the VPN tunnel
- there must be no DNS / webrtc / other leaks (for some reason I always have to manually remove the 192.168... ip from resolv.conf on each startup)

I'm using the standard Network Manager and OpenVPN protocol. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1. In the notification area right-click on the Network Manager Applet. In the context menu left-click on "Edit Connections". Now choose your local Wi-Fi or Ethernet connection, and click on "Edit". In the editor open the tap "General" and activate "Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection".
2. Then you set the DNS in the resolv.conf file. If you want to prevent any further automatic change, open the console with Ctrl+Alt+T and type the command:

   sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf

After rebooting the problem should be solved. More details about step two I posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453970/184608).